# Leaflet, keeping the last marker only

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I am using leaflet to display maps on my site. I want user to show and save his address on the map (by placing a marker) so in my code, if user double clicks, a marker will be placed on the map. The problem is I don't want to disable double click zoom. So when user double clicks again, the previous marker should be deleted and a new marker should be added.
I searched Stack Overflow and reached to this code

```
map.on('dblclick', addMarker);
var Marker;
function addMarker(e) {
    //remove previous markers
    map.removeLayer(Marker);
    // Add marker to map at click location; add popup window
     Marker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{draggable:true}).addTo(map);
}
```

But after adding "map.removeLayer (Marker);" not only double click zoom stopped working, but also no marker is added to map anymore
Summary: I always want to keep the last marker added to map

Answer (score 4):

The script stops working on first double click because it tries to remove `Marker` which is not assigned yet at initialization.

Once the error occurs, the rest of your JS function stops: no marker added, no double click zoom.

Simply check that `Marker` is assigned before trying to remove it.

```js
map.on('dblclick', addMarker);
var Marker;

function addMarker(e) {
  //remove previous markers
  if (Marker) {
    map.removeLayer(Marker);
  }
  // Add marker to map at click location; add popup window
  Marker = new L.marker(e.latlng, {
    draggable: true
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/26/